# Removing old directories with logs

Tags: bash

My IM stores the logs according to the contact name. I have created a file with the list of active contacts. My problem is following:

I would like to create a bash script with read the active contacts names from the file and compare it with the directories. If the directory name wouldn't be found on the list, it would be moved to another directory (let's call it "archive"). I try to visualise it for you.

- content of the list:

contact1
contact2

- content of the dir

contact1
contact2
contact3
contact4

- after running of the script, the content fo the dir:

contact1
contact2

contact3 ==> ../archive
contact4 ==> ../archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an improved version of marcog's answer. Note that the associative array requires Bash 4.

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcedir=/path/to/foo
destdir=/path/to/archive
contactfile=/path/to/list

declare -A contacts

while read -r contact
do
    contacts[$contact]=1
done < "$contactfile"

for contact in "$sourcedir"/*
do
    if [[ -f $contact ]]
    then
        index=${contact##*/}
        if [[ ! ${contacts[$index]} ]]
        then
            mv "$contact" "$destdir"
        fi
    fi
done
```

**Edit:**

If you're moving directories instead of files, then change the `for` loop above to look like this:

```
for contact in "$sourcedir"/*/
do
    index=${contact/%\/}
    index=${index##*/}
    if [[ ! ${contacts[$index]} ]]
    then
        mv "$contact" "$destdir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Denis... sorry but isn't working either. I added a "echo test" lines in each part in loops. It seems that none "if's" inside of the "for contact in "$sourcedir"/* do" loop to be working

Comment: @Mcgiwer: That would seem to indicate that all the entries in `"$sourcedir"` are directories and none are regular files. If these are directories that you want to move, then see my edited answer for a version to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
mv $(ls | grep -v -x -F -f ../file.txt) ../archive
```

Where **../file.txt** contains the names of the directories that should not be moved. It is assumed here that the current directory only contains directories, if that is not the case, `ls` should be replaced with something else. Note that the command fails if there are no directories that should be moved.

Since in the comments to the other answer you state that directories with whitespace in the name can occur, you could replace this by:

```
for i in *
do
    echo $i | grep -v -x -q -F -f ../file.txt && mv "$i" ../archive
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more concise solution, but this works. I'd strongly recommend prefixing the `mv` with `echo` to test it out first, otherwise you could end up with a serious mess if it doesn't do what you want.

```
declare -A contacts
for contact in "$@"
do
  contacts[$contact]=1
done
ls a | while read contact
do
  if [[ ! ${contacts[$contact]} ]]
  then
    mv "a/$contact" ../archive
  fi
done
```

Comment: Does this work as well if one of the contact's names include whitespaces resp. special characters?

Comment: @philonous No, I'll fix that. I also just realised I misread the question so I'll fix that too.

Comment: Fixed, it handles whitespace in filenames but will fail if the name contains double quotes. I'm not sure how you'd fix that.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the script moves all dirs into ../archive instead of those with aren't on the list in the file

Comment: @Mcgiwer It reads the command-line args from `$@` as its list. If you already have another list, replace `$@` with your list.

Comment: @Mcgiwer I used the directory name `a`. You should rename that to the directory containing the contact files. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: @marcog I modiffied the code to fit my situation and as I wrote, it removes anything to the "archive" folder

Comment: @Mcgiwer Can you post your modified code? There must be something wrong with your edits, because it works fine here.

Comment: Modified code:

#!/bin/bash

from=./mcgiwer
list=./yahoo.list

declare -A contacts

for contact in $list
do
  echo $contact
  contacts[$contact]=1
done
ls $from | while read contact
do
  if [[ ! ${contacts[$contact]} ]]
  then
    mv "$from/"$contact ./archive
  fi
done

Comment: question: shouldn't be the line: "ls a | while read contact" be as following: "ls a | while read $contact" ?

Comment: @Mcgiwer Change `./yahoo.list` to `yahoo.list`.

Comment: @Mcgiwer No. When setting a variable, you don't prefix a `$`.

Comment: but while "read contact" the script isn't setting the variable, but it reading it

Comment: hmm... the result is the same

Comment: It's not necessary to escape the quotes. I think you had it that way so they'd show up when you were echoing the `mv` command. Just do `mv "a/$contact" ../archive`

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, made that change.